# Does AWS Lambda store jar somewhere?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, version

I upload jars to S3 as part of my Make commands. This jar replaces any existing jar with an identical name. I want to understand how Lambda reads from the jar every time it is triggered? Does it save the jar somewhere when the jar is uploaded from the S3 path? Or does it read the jar every time from the provided S3 path?

Answer (score 1):

> Or does it read the jar every time from the provided S3 path?

The short answer is: **no**. The JAR file is not read every time the Lambda is "triggered".

---

**Long answer:**

Under the hood AWS Lambda uses micro virtual machines (microVM) based on [FireCracker](https://firecracker-microvm.github.io). Think of it as a small, isolated virtualised computer.

For our purposes this mciroVM has to states:

1. It is running *and* accepting requests.
2. It is not running.

So what happens if your Lambda is *not* running and is triggered? Then the AWS Lambda *service* will "boot" a microVM, download the JAR from S3 and *launch* your JAR. This will start a *long running* application that is accepting requests. That is something the AWS SDK does under the hood for you.

After the request has been processed, the application/Lambda is *NOT* shutdown. Remember, it is a virtualised computer and it wouldn't be a very efficient thing to start and stop the VM for every request.

What happens is that the microVM will continue to run for a certain time. If no requests are received, the AWS Lambda service will shutdown the microVM sooner or later. If that happens, the next time your Lambda is triggered, a new microVM will be created and the JAR is downloaded from S3 for that.